# Robotframework Windows 10: Why test status (Pass/fail) not in color green/red

Tags: windows, frameworks, robotframework

i'm using Gitbash in windows 10 to start my robot framework test. It works fine but i'm missing the color of the test status. I mean in the console Pass should be marked in Green und Fail in red. Why I don't have this color in my console ? Any idea to fix this ?

[screenshot of uncolorized text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWk2X.png)

Comment: Tried every possible command line/terminal on my Win10 laptop:

 - Command prompt is colorized
 - Command prompt opened in VS Code is colorized
 - WSL terminal is colorized
 - WSL terminal in VS Code is colorized

Comment: Hi, i'm using Git Bash to run a bash file which calls the robot framework test and the results are not colorized :(

Comment: I would probably recommend installing WSL.

Comment: Can I install it without admin right?